# Simple Menu with ror and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a simple menu with ruby on rails and Jquery.
What means that I have super categories and categories, and I want when I put the mouse on a super category, I want to show in another div the categories that belongs to that super category.

```
<p></p>
<div class="tabbable tabs-left" >
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="prueba1">
    <% @super_categories.each do |sc| %>
      <li><%=sc.name%></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="prueba2">
      <div class="tab-content">

      <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $("#prueba1").mouseover(
          function () {
            $(prueba2).empty();
            $(prueba2).append($("
              <% @super_categories.each do |sc| %>
               <div id = <%=sc.name.to_s%> class = "tab-pane">
                  <% sc.categories.each do |cat|%>
                    <li><%=cat.name %></li>
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>"));
            }
          );     
        </script>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

But of course It doesn't works.
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I would take a totally different approach - render all the categories and subcategories using the ERB template and make them hidden by default. Once we read a mouseover event on Category1 then show the subcategories for Category1 and the same goes for 2,3,4

Comment: I'll do that! 
thanks!